# " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure' " after importing azure.datalake.store even though it is installed

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, modulenotfounderror

I have tried installing and re-installing the package multiple times (pip install azure-datalake-store) to solve this problem but nothing will work. I have have multiple other imports that all work, but "from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread" keeps giving me a ModuleNotFoundError. Any advice to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: You should specify the "everything" so people know what not to suggest and might also point towards what the actual problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this  command explicitly to have successful import as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks/issues/460)

```
!pip install azure-datalake-store
```

Comment: This is the following output I get when I run that command in Terminal: " pip3 install azure-datalake-store install azure-datalake-store
Requirement already satisfied: azure-datalake-store in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.48)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for install "